# How to install Phalcon php

Tags: php, installation, phalcon

I downloaded Phalcon from official website
I copied php_phalcon.dll file to my xampp's php/ext directory
Edited the php.ini file located at D:\xampp\php\php.ini. and add there line extension=php_phalcon.dll at the end of the file.
I Restarted apache server and computer several times.

When I write phpinfo() to my code it seems phalcon was installed
[image]
[image]
Unfortunatelly Whan I try to run some code like

```
<?php 

try {
    // Autoloader
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs([
        '../app/controllers/',
        '../app/models/'
    ]);
    $loader->register();

    // Dependency Injection
    $di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
    $di->set('view', function() {
        $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
        $view->setViewsDir('../app/views');
        return $view;
    });

    // Deploy the App
    $app = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
    echo $app->handle()->getContent();

} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I get this error
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Loader' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\php-learning\public\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\php-learning\public\index.php on line 4**

I also tried to follow the steps from tutorial on Phalcon ofical website where code looks somehow like this

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\Url;

// Define some absolute path constants to aid in locating resources
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('APP_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/app');

// Register an autoloader
$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        APP_PATH . '/controllers/',
        APP_PATH . '/models/',
    ]
);

$loader->register();

$container = new FactoryDefault();

$container->set(
    'view',
    function () {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setViewsDir(APP_PATH . '/views/');
        return $view;
    }
);

$container->set(
    'url',
    function () {
        $url = new Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/');
        return $url;
    }
);

$application = new Application($container);

try {
    // Handle the request
    $response = $application->handle(
        $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
    );

    $response->send();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

But didn´t help. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: For windows, you need to download the right phalcon dll file to match your architecture and php version. This is an older video, but the concept remains the same: https://vimeo.com/40265988?embedded=true&source=vimeo_logo&owner=11016979 Based on your screenshot, it looks like you need VC15, probably NTS, php 7.4, and x64:https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases

Comment: sorry, looks like you need TS. (not NTS)

Comment: From [download page](https://phalcon.io/en-us/download/windows), they said "_The PSR extension is required to be loaded before Phalcon. Please ensure that it is available in your system_". Do you installed it? And I recommend you to follow the document especially [basic tutorial](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/tutorial-basic).

Comment: ya, need psr and pdo extensions. load them before phalcon

Comment: Things might get complicated with Tread Safe php as well. I'd almost reinstall xampp as NTS. Almost everyone uses the NTS php build. There's some bugs with phalcon in TS mode such as where every second request on top of the first can seg fault rooted in zephir.

Comment: I would recommend using PHP 7.4 with Phalcon 4.2 (as mentioned before, you will have to install Php-PSR first) and PHP 8+ with Phalcon 5. 4.2 runs very well on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have Phalcon installed successfully. However the namespace should be changed:

- Moved Phalcon\Loader to Phalcon\Autoload\Loader #15797

please refer to the change log
[enter link description here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/CHANGELOG-5.0.md)